# Uppercase/lowercase conversion skipping some letters

Tags: c, string, input, fgets

This is a program for converting lower case letters in a string to upper case and vice versa in C language.

In this code I am trying to take input string `str` from user using `fgets()` function but it is not working. I even tried using `gets()` but it is also not working.
It skips taking input and execute the program.
What can I do?
I tried using `for` loop but it is not terminating on new line.
Can I do it with any function or using any loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char lower(char *str);
char upper(char *str);

int main() {
    
    char *newstr;
    char ans;
    printf("Enter U for Lower case -> Upper case\nEnter L for Upper case -> Lower case:\n");
    scanf("%c", &ans);

    char str[100];
    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    if (ans == 'U' || ans == 'u') {
        // newstr = upper(str);
        upper(str);
    }
    else if(ans == 'L' || ans == 'l') {
        // newstr = lower(str);
        lower(str);
    }
    else {
        printf("Try entering a valid input.");
    }
    
    // printf("%s", newstr);
    printf("%s", str);
    
    return 0;
}

char lower(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++) {
        char c[] = { str[i], '\0' };
        if (strstr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", c)) {
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        }
    }
    // return str;
}

char upper(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++) {
        char c[] = { str[i], '\0' };
        if (strstr("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", c)) {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
        }
    }
    // return str;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, and the solution to your assignment would be very different in the two languages. Please don't add language-tags that might *seem* similar.

Comment: As for the problem, your `scanf` call will leave the newline added by the `Enter` key in the input buffer. That will be the first character that `fgets` reads.

Comment: sorry I recently started C so didn't knew

Comment: And *please* use [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) and [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) instead of using encoding-specific arithmetic and [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: ok then should I use a getchar() function befor that?

Comment: I tried to do it without using/using minimum built in functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256635/discussion-between-shashank-gupta-and-some-programmer-dude).

Answer (score 2):

1. If you do not want to use `toupper` and `tolower` you should use conversion table. It may also simplify the code (only one function needed)
2. `scanf` leaves new line in the buffer, better read the string. Then you can `sscanf` the string.
3. You function should return `char *`
4. `strchr` suits better your needs and it is much faster.
5. `fgets`leaves ''\n`` in the string - it should be removed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convert(char *str, int direction);


int main(void){
    
    char *newstr;
    int ans;
    char str[100] = "";

    printf("Enter 1 for Lower case -> Upper case\nAnything else for Upper case -> Lower case:\n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    if(sscanf(str, "%d", &ans) != 1) { /* handle error */ }

    printf("\nEnter the string:\n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    for(char *wrk = str; *wrk; wrk++)
       if(*wrk == '\n') *wrk = 0;

    printf("\"%s\"\n", convert(str, ans != 1));
}

static char *conversionArray[2] = 
{
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
};


char *convert(char *str, int direction)
{
    char *wrk = str, *found;
    while(*wrk)
    {
        found = strchr(conversionArray[direction], *wrk);
        if(found) *wrk = conversionArray[!direction][found - conversionArray[direction]];
        wrk++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> fgets() - *Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.*

Answer: the `scanf()` statement is leaving a newline character in the input buffer, which is causing `fgets()` to take it as an input and end the string.

You can modify your code and move the `fgets()` logic before the `scanf` statement to make it work. Additionally, if conditions can be modified a little bit to make it better using ASCII values. Below is an example of working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
void lower(char *str);
void upper(char *str);
int main() {
    char str[MAX];
    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    fgets(str, MAX, stdin);
    char ans;
    printf("Enter U for Lower case -> Upper case\nEnter L for Upper case -> Lower case:\n");
    scanf("%c", &ans);
    if (ans == 'U' || ans == 'u') {
        upper(str);
    } else if (ans == 'L' || ans == 'l') {
        lower(str);
    } else {
        printf("Try entering a valid input.");
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
void lower(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++) {
        //A = 65, Z = 90
        if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
        }
    }
}
void upper(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++) {
        //a = 97, z = 122
        if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) {
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_Additionally, `if` conditions can be modified a little bit to make it better using ASCII values._" -- It would be better to use `char` constants instead of magic numbers, e.g., `if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')`, and `int case_diff = 'a' - 'A'` lets you do `str[i] + case_diff`. These are more clear than the ASCII code alternatives. But note that C does not require ASCII encoding so this is not a portable approach. OP's idea of using `strstr` is not complete, but with some adjustments and using `strchr` this is in fact portable.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` leads to surprises as `scanf()` leaves the newline typed by the user pending in the input stream and `fgets()` reads it and returns immediately with an empty line.
- your test for upper and lower case is very cumbersome. You should use `isupper`, `islower` and/or `tolower` and `toupper` from `<ctype.h>` instead of hardcoding a difference of 32 between cases that is specific to `ASCII`.
- `lower` and `upper` should have a return type of `char *` so you can return the string pointer.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *lower(char *str);
char *upper(char *str);

int main(void) {
    char str[100];
    char *newstr;
    char ans;

    printf("Enter U for Lower case -> Upper case\n"
           "Enter L for Upper case -> Lower case:\n");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    ans = (char)toupper((unsigned char)*str);
    if (ans != 'U' && ans != 'L') {
        printf("Try entering a valid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    if (ans == 'U') {
        newstr = upper(str);
    } else {
        newstr = lower(str);
    }
    printf("%s", newstr);
    return 0;
}

char *lower(char *str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        str[i] = (char)tolower((unsigned char)str[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

char *upper(char *str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        str[i] = (char)toupper((unsigned char)str[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void lower(char *str);
void upper(char *str);

int main() {
    
    char ans;
    printf("Enter U for Lower case -> Upper case\nEnter L for Upper case -> Lower case:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ans);  
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    getchar();  // Consume the newline character left by the previous scanf
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    
    if (ans == 'U' || ans == 'u') {
        upper(str);
    }
    else if(ans == 'L' || ans == 'l') {
        lower(str);
    }
    else {
        printf("Try entering a valid input.");
    }
    
    printf("%s", str);
    
    return 0;
}

void lower(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
            str[i] += 32;
        }
    }
}

void upper(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
            str[i] -= 32;
        }
    }
}
```